# Unable to pass the right parameter to action in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

```
Rails 3.2.2
```

This code throws an exception `ArgumentError missing :action` even when I go to the page `/my_controller/some_action1`

```
#routes
namespace :my_controller do 
    get 'some_action1'
    get 'some_action2/:some_param1'

  end

#Controller
class MyController < ApplicationController
 def some_action1
 end

 def some_action2
  #handling the ajax request
  respond_to do |format|
     format.js
  end
 end

end

#View /my_controller/some_action1.html.haml
link_to "my_link", {:controller => :my_controller, :action => :some_action2,
                             :some_param1=>123}, :remote=>true, :id=>"unique_id123"
```

Your thoughts?

Comment: That's not how you should use [namespaces](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing). Erez' answer seems the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace your routes with these:

```
match '/my_controller/some_action1' => "my_controller#some_action1", :via => :get
match '/my_controller/some_action2/:some_param1' => "my_controller#some_action2", :via => :get
```